# How to apply a XSLT template to an element as many times as number of another element in the document?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

This is kind of hard for me to express in English so an example might help. Let's say I have several elements called sentence which consists of several terms. In another part of XML there is a set of elements with language codes. I would like to apply a template for every sentence as many times as number of languages and call that template with appropriate language code. From this:

```
<description>
    <sentences>
        <sentence>
            <term type="adjective">nice</term>
            <term type="tripType">cycling</term>
        </sentence>
        <sentence>
            <term type="adjective">boring</term>
            <term type="tripType">hike</term>
        </sentence>
    </sentences>
    <languages>
        <l>cs</l>
        <l>en</l>
    </languages>
</description>
```

I want to produce something like this:

```
<div>
 <p><span>cs</span> nice cycling</p>
 <p><span>en</span> nice cycling</p>
</div>

<div>    
 <p><span>cs</span> boring hike</p>
 <p><span>en</span> boring hike</p>
</div>
```

I was trying to use `<xsl:for-each select="/description/languages/l">` but that sets the content of `l` as current element and I'm not able to get to the term stuff anymore.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign the current element (the term stuff, if I have correctly understood) to a variable and then use that variable in the for-each loop: `<xsl:variable name="term" select="current()"/>`

Comment: Thanks Oliver, but that just puts in the variable another copy of the contents of `l` elemnent (language code)

Comment: Not if you do it outside of your for-each loop. I think you should post more of your code.

Comment: You're right, I just realized what you meant the second I post the comment. Thanks a lot Oliver, this was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:template match="description">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="sentences/sentence" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sentence">
  <xsl:variable name="terms" select="term" />
  <div>
    <xsl:for-each select="../../languages/l">
      <p>
        <span><xsl:value-of select="." /></span>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$terms" />
      </p>
    <xsl:for-each>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="term">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
  <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()"> </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I figured it out with Oliver's help, but I'll try also your solution, seems to be more elegant than my code.

Comment: I was wondering if the term template in your code could somehow recieve the language code from the sentence template it was called with? I guess that would need some use of `<xsl:call-template>`, right?

Comment: Replying to myself :) It can be passed by adding `<xsl:with-param name="language_code" select="." />` within `<xsl:apply-templates select="$terms" />`.

Comment: @Lukas Exactly what I was going to say.

Answer (score 1):

**This simple transformation (no explicit conditionals)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="sentence">
  <xsl:variable name="vSentence" select="."/>
  <div>
       <xsl:for-each select="/*/languages/l">
         <p>
           <span><xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="$vSentence/term"/>
         </p>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </div>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="term[position() > 1]">
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="l"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<description>
    <sentences>
        <sentence>
            <term type="adjective">nice</term>
            <term type="tripType">cycling</term>
        </sentence>
        <sentence>
            <term type="adjective">boring</term>
            <term type="tripType">hike</term>
        </sentence>
    </sentences>
    <languages>
        <l>cs</l>
        <l>en</l>
    </languages>
</description>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<div>
   <p><span>cs</span>nice cycling</p>
   <p><span>en</span>nice cycling</p>
</div>
<div>
   <p><span>cs</span>boring hike</p>
   <p><span>en</span>boring hike</p>
</div>
```